# Best way to check for Office (Word) 2007

Tags: c#, ms-word, ms-office

I have setup spell checking through WinWord but I need to find a way to in sure that Word 2007 is installed on there systems.

I have seen the Registry Versions of this but I also read that it can provide false positives.  So I am in the 'market' as it were to figure out how to accomplish this.  Can it be as simple as doing a `File.Exists()` on WinWord.exe in the 2007 file path?

Any other ideas?

Comment: The file path could easily be different on different machines. For example, 64-bit versions of windows place 32-bit apps (like Office) into the "Program Files(x86)" folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Type word = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application");
if (word != null) {
    // Word is installed
}
```

To check that Word 2007 in particular is installed:

```
Type word = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Word.Application.12");
if (word != null) {
    // Word 2007 is installed
}
```

Comment: Does the ProdID "Word.Application" specifically find Word 2007?

Comment: Sorry, that comment was ambiguous - to be more specific I meant to say the author requested Word 2007 be identified to the exclusion of other versions of Word on the system.

Comment: Very, very nifty.  Thanks!  I was told at the onset that ALL systems would be Office 2007 but the reality is that they all WILL be but currently are not and I only implemented 07 spell checking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are worried about the registry and false positives you can look at the exe version.  Microsoft documents how to determine the executable version [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928116)

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be use a combination.  Use the registry to get the installation path.  Inside of that path, you should find the executable.  A false positive occurs because upgrades and uninstalls will sometimes remove the file but not the registry entry.